# Simultaneously habitat fragmentation metrics calculation within more buffers

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer, habitat-modeling

Within several raster buffers I need to calculate habitat fragmentation metrics (i.e., number of patches, mean patch area, Euclidean distance among patches, landscape proportion) using the landscape statistics tool. Here an example:

[image]

However, because I have several buffers, I would like to know if there is an existing method in QGIS to calculate such metrics simultaneously and not considering each buffer one-to-one.

Comment: Have you tried running the task with the "Batch processing" and selecting all the layers?

Comment: I tried. Unfortunately, it's not possible to select more than one raster layer.